# If i add file path of image in mongodb database, will image be displayed?

Tags: mongodb

I am using django with mongodb.I want to add images in mongodb. If i add file path of image , will that image be displayed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends whether you uploaded your image in your project folder or in cloud.

If its uploaded in project folder then you have to append your static folder URL + your image name.

If its uploaded in cloud such as S3 bucket then only S3 bucket URL will do.